# candidate in me?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

> A: Who's going to be my partner?
>
> B: Maybe I will.
>
> C: But you also have an exceptional candidate in me!

Why did C say like that? What is the meaning of 'in' here?

Comment: It means the same as "You **see in me** an exceptional candidate", or in other words, "You **see me as** an exceptional candidate".

Comment: B should be "Maybe I will", or "Maybe I'll be'. Nobody says the bare shortened form of 'will', 'am', 'are', etc at the end of a sentence or utterance like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the Randy Newman song "You've Got a Friend in Me", it's the same use of *in*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You%27ve_Got_a_Friend_in_Me

"You've got a friend in me" = "I am your friend"

"You have an exceptional candidate in me" = "I am an exceptional candidate for you"

Answer (score 0):

C thinks he/she is a good partner for A.

However, it doesn't necessarily mean that A *[sees](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see-sth-in-sb-sth)* an exceptional candidate *in* C.

Comment: I'm less confident that C actually thinks they would be a good partner. However, regardless of how they personally feel about it, they're attempting to make the claim that they would be.